# how to make div elements display inline (other version)

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, inline

I've read that someone asked the same question but with a different layout/purpose..

I can't seem to figure out the answer given because my code looks actually quite diffrent because i am using a div inside a div, because I will need this in future coding..

I need the words to display inline, but so that I can still move each one sepperatly, now they are all in a line under eachother like this, http://prntscr.com/a0ivs5

This is my code,

```css
body, html {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: georgia, "Comic Sans MS";
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

header {
  height: 5%;
  border-bottom: thick solid grey;
}

.img {
  width: 25%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color:#f0f0f0;
  float: left;
}
.antwoord {
  float: left;
  width: 95%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-width: 4px;
}

.move1 {

}
.move2 {
  margin-top: 12.5%
}
.move4 {
margin-top: 19%
}
.move5 {
margin-top: 33.5%
}
.move6 {
margin-top: 20.8%
}
.move7 {
margin-top: 37.5%
}

.word {
  float: left;
}

footer {
    border-top: thick solid grey;
    height: 5%;
}

.points {
    float: right;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
}
.igen {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.sprint {
  float: right;
}
.copyright {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 65px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Words</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <script>

  </script>

</head>
<body>

<header>
 <span class="fa fa-refresh" style="font-size:25px;"></span><span class="igen">&nbsp;igen</span>
 <span class="points"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="font-size:24px"></i>Rigtige:  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 0 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down" style="font-size:24px"></i>Forkerte: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 0</span>
</header>

<div class="container">


      <div class="img" id="img1">
          <div class="plaatje" id="plaatje1"><center><img src="img/cat.jpg" alt="cat" width="50%;"></div>
          <div class="move1"><div class="antwoord" id="antwoord1"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="img" id="img2">
          <div class="plaatje" id="plaatje1"><center><img src="img/beak.jpg" alt="beak" width="50%;"></div>
            <div class="move2"><div class="antwoord" id="antwoord2"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="img" id="img3">
          <div class="plaatje" id="plaatje3"><center><img src="img/spoon.jpg" alt="spoon" width="50%;"></div>
          <div class="move3"><div class="antwoord" id="antwoord3"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="img" id="img4">
          <div class="plaatje" id="plaatje4"><center><img src="img/milk.jpg" alt="milk" width="50%;"></div>
          <div class="move4"><div class="antwoord" id="antwoord4"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="img" id="img5">
          <div class="plaatje" id="plaatje5"><center><img src="img/egg.jpg" alt="egg" width="50%;"></div>
          <div class="move5"><div class="antwoord" id="antwoord5"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="img" id="img6">
          <div class="plaatje" id="plaatje6"><center><img src="img/thee.jpg" alt="tea" width="50%;"></div>
          <div class="move6"><div class="antwoord" id="antwoord6"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="img" id="img7">
          <div class="plaatje" id="plaatje7"><center><img src="img/meel.jpg" alt="meel" width="50%;"></div>
          <div class="move7"><div class="antwoord" id="antwoord7"></div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="img" id="img8">
              <div class="plaatje" id="plaatje8"><center><img src="img/passport.jpg" alt="passport" width="50%;"></div>
          <div class="move8"><div class="antwoord" id="antwoord8"></div></div>
          </div>

<div class="Word" id="word1">
  <div class="tekst" id="tekst1"> <p>Cat</p> </div>
</div>
<div class="Word" id="word2">
  <div class="tekst" id="tekst2"> <p>spoon</p> </div>
</div>
<div class="Word" id="word3">
  <div class="tekst" id="tekst3"> <p>meal</p> </div>
</div>
<div class="Word" id="word4">
  <div class="tekst" id="tekst4"> <p>passport</p> </div>
</div>
<div class="Word" id="word5">
  <div class="tekst" id="tekst5"> <p>egg</p> </div>
</div>
<div class="Word" id="word6">
  <div class="tekst" id="tekst6"> <p>beak</p> </div>
</div>
<div class="Word" id="word7">
  <div class="tekst" id="tekst7"> <p>tea</p> </div>
</div>
<div class="Word" id="word8">
  <div class="tekst" id="tekst8"> <p>milk</p> </div>
</div>

<footer>
<img class="dansk" id="dansk" src="img/dansk2.jpg" alt="dansk" />
<img class="sprint" id="sprint" src="img/sprint2.png" alt="sprint" />
<center><span class="copyright"> &copy;2013 laerdansk / FC-Sprint&sup2; Leerbedrijf bronnen </span></center>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

I probably did other stuff in my code not so efficient eighter, but I know not another way to do so yet, I am quite new in programming..

It's a little game where the words need to be dropped into the table's under the images..

If somebody has any tips for me, those are always welcome too ofcourse :D
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that CSS class names are case-sensitive, `.word {...}` will not work for `<div class="Word">...</div>`

Anyway, your words are wrapped in 3 `block` level elements, you'd have to make them all inline to get your desired effect

> `div.Word > div.tekst > p`

```
.Word, .Word .tekst, .Word p {
  display:inline;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/w482fapd/)**

```css
body,
html {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: georgia, "Comic Sans MS";
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
}

.Word, .Word .tekst, .Word p {
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="Word" id="word1">
    <div class="tekst" id="tekst1">
      <p>Cat</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Word" id="word2">
    <div class="tekst" id="tekst2">
      <p>spoon</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Word" id="word3">
    <div class="tekst" id="tekst3">
      <p>meal</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Word" id="word4">
    <div class="tekst" id="tekst4">
      <p>passport</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Word" id="word5">
    <div class="tekst" id="tekst5">
      <p>egg</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Word" id="word6">
    <div class="tekst" id="tekst6">
      <p>beak</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Word" id="word7">
    <div class="tekst" id="tekst7">
      <p>tea</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Word" id="word8">
    <div class="tekst" id="tekst8">
      <p>milk</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

P.S you have some syntax errors

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, your problem is that your ".word" class is lowercase while it is referenced in the HTML as "Word". So try changing the .word class to

```
.Word { display: inline-block; }
```

Changing the above makes all the words that were displaying line after line in one line now.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qorxcq8p/2/)

Comment: it does set everything line after line in one line.. but all the words are following up on eachother, I've tried several things already, do you maybe know a solution for that? 

thanks a bunch btw for that comment, I should've seen that xD  @Timble

Comment: No problem, I didn't catch a capitalization error twice the other day in my own code haha. Do you mean the words are displaying like "Catspoonmealpassport..." etc? If so, instead of having the .Word class set to "float: left;" try setting it to as I showed above, " display:inline-block;"

Comment: thanks! I've figured it out by you and @Aziz, sadly enough I can't vote for your both answers to be the right one, but thanks a lot both of you, I can work alot further again now!